# jquery element cannot call from displayed json

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, element

I'm having a hard time trying to solve this.

Here is my sample code:

```
$.ajax({
 url: 'json.php',
 data: {some_data:some_value},
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function(){
   $('.some_element').append('<div class="myElement">Click Me</div>');
 }
```

Then, I have added the following code, this is the code where I am having the problem:

```
$('.myElement').click(function(){
 alert('It works!');//BUT it's not working.
})
```

Any advice, idea?

Thanks Guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working becuase `.click()` is a wrapper around [`.bind()`](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) which only binds to *elements that exist at the time of the call*. Use a [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) event, which will make the event trigger for all current *and future* elements that match your selector.

```
$('.myElement').live('click', function() {
    alert('It works!'); //This will work.
})
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
$('.myElement').live('click',function(){
 alert('It works!');
})
```

Comment: @loviji : are you lovjii who know r00t and [nobodies] back in 20xx?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.some_element').on('click','.myElement',function(){
 alert('It works!');//BUT it's not working.
})
```

1.7+